# Is navigator keyword possible to store in a variable

Tags: javascript

I just wonder if a navigator keyword is possible to store in a variable. Cause I saw a program wherein there is a line of code which goes like this.

```
function Ddmenu(k)
{
    "use strict";
    var p=function(a,b)
        {
            return a.getElementsByTagName(b)
        },

    o=navigator,
    H=function(a,c)
        {
            if(typeof getComputedStyle!="undefined")
            var b=getComputedStyle(a,null);
            else if(a.currentStyle)b=a.currentStyle;
            else b=a.style;
            return b[c]
        },
......
}
```

a variable o holds a value which is a navigator.

Comment: Uhm... yes!? It's just an object. You can assign it to another variable like any other object.

Comment: So you're asking if a program, which presumably works, is capable of doing something it is clearly doing?

Answer (score 0):

*Anything* is possible to be stored in a variable - in this case a *reference* to [`window.navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator) is stored in a variable named `o`.

Nothing to see here!